# Modern UI Metro Framework control buttons disappeared

Tags: c#, modern-ui

Eeerrm, all of a sudden, my Modern UI Metro Framework control buttons disappeared...have not changed anything in code nor in properties since last run.
Now I can't minimize, maximize, close the window.

[image]

Any ideas how to get them back?

On a side note, a different but slightly related question. Why can't I move the form if I grab it where a `TableLayoutPanel` is used? It only works if I click elsewhere.

Comment: EDIT: there might have been a problem caused by one of the DataSets, at least all my controls are back after changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `Theme` or `Style` property in your form. In your picture, your form looks black, I assume that you accidentally change the `Theme` property to `Dark`.

Comment: I indeed changed the Form's Theme property to Dark, not accidentally but on purpose, and it was still working this way so far. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Now go to references and then add the three respective `.dll` files of the Metro UI to your form. If it doesn't work, please comment and we will find it together.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem when changing the culture of my Modern Metro Form and after that my control buttons (i.e. maximize, minimize and close) disappeared. I found out that it was because I do `Controls.Clear()` which removes all controls including `ControlBox`, `MinimizeBox`, `MaximizeBox`.

I found out that the properties called `ControlBox`, `MinimizeBox`, `MaximizeBox` when set to true, appears on the right upper corner of the form as maximize, minimize and close buttons. Anyone coming here in the future might want to check these properties.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop Controlbox from Toolbox to MetroSetUI forms
if initial form not set controlbox automatically

[image]